# Issue with VBA else without if showing an error

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I am using the following VBA *Else-If* code:

```
If ActiveSheet.Range(range_name).Value < "8.50%" Then
   ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(shape_name)).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(192, 0, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
    ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range(range_name).Value < "9.70%" Then
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(shape_name)).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    Else
     ActiveSheet.Shapes.Range(Array(shape_name)).Select
    With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 255, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With
```

When I run this, I receive an error: "Else without If ".
So, I changed the *Else* line to:

```
 ElseIf ActiveSheet.Range(range_name).Value >= "9.70%" Then
```

But still, it is giving me the same error, even though this *Else* has an *If*

Why is that? And the first code is also correct and shouldn't give an error in the first place. So why is this happening? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you're missing an `End With` in the middle, i.e. this part

```
With Selection.ShapeRange.Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 0)
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
```

Comment: agree with sam. all `With` statement within your `If` statement should be ended.

Answer (score 1):

add this:

```
End If
```

on the last line.
This is to terminate the `if` statement like what you did in your `With` statement.

Comment: Ya that that i wrote, i forgot to paste it here. Anyway thanks :)

Comment: anytime mate. :) we're glad to be of help. to avoid such, at the beginning of your code, end all statements that needs to be ended. then right your events in the middle.